# Migrate from WSL2 to Raspberry 4 with Docker

Tags: pi-4

I am planning to use a Raspberry Pi 4.0 B as the new home for my current distro of Ubuntu which is located in WSL2 in Win10. Now as I understand I can export the files, but is there any way to get it running in a docker of the new Raspberry Pi? Because Raspberry Pi works on the ARM platform, I am not sure whether the [only instruction I found](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/d3dd81/how_to_convert_your_wsl_file_system_into_a_docker/) might work.

Does somebody has a advice or idea how to manage this? Or better to install and configure everything from zero?

Comment: Since you cant use the docker images from the WSL2 (different CPU) isn't following the instruction feasible. And then it depends if you have structured your docker in a correct way (templates and data folders) and have you used docker-compose?
So there is some missing info to give a proper answer.

Comment: @MatsK I don't believe the OP means transferring Docker images, but rather, he wants to run an exact duplicate of his WSL environment on the RPi. He wants to migrate the system, along with all of its configuration, and believes that Docker images are the way to accomplish this.

Comment: @rokdd Your best bet is to install and configure everything on your RPi from scratch, and transfer the files over. It will take much less time than attempting to migrate your WSL with all of its specific configuration and settings, which could be a dead end.

Comment: @user96931 I believe the same, but I rather ask and don't assume, that's how Stackexchange works.

Comment: Well thanks both of you! I also noticed two days ago that it is the best way instead of trying bringing the whole ubuntu as image into docker container. Nevertheless I would have to reinstall Ubuntu as a new image and copying all settings and modifications because of wrong platform architecture. So I guess the only way is to compose the docker images :-)

Comment: @rokdd Could you write your comment as an answer ans select it as the answer to your question, that would help others that is looking for answers.

Answer (score 2):

Like discussed in the comments a summary how I solved the problem (or even not)

It makes not so much sense to import the Ubuntu of WSL as a image/container because:

- architecture of both platforms are different (arm of Raspberry PI)
- the Ubuntu might be slightly customized and even not running "normal"
- it is not the concept of docker to put all applications in one docker

So I broke them down in multiple images:

- nextcloud
- postgres
- redis
- adminer